# Standard library missing on Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, standard-library, crystal-lang

I've been using Crystal in OS X, installed with Homebrew. Now I'm giving it a try on Linux, but when I compile a project that includes `URI` from the standard library, I get:

> while requiring "URI": can't find file 'URI' relative to '/home/...'

I installed according to the docs using `apt-get`. (I'm actually using LinuxMint if that matters.) Do I need to download the git repo as well? If so, where does Crystal expect it to be?

---

I downloaded a precompiled binary. I see it includes the standard library. Is there a PATH that Crystal looks for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `require "uri"` in lowercase. OSX filesystem is case insensitive (by default).

Comment: Ugh, that was it. I was thinking of the class name. Thank you!